# Why does Team Machine need to save the Machine instead of creating a new

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

In Person of Interest, we know that the Machine is created by Harold. The power only comes to the machine by getting data from feeds, otherwise, the logic/structure was provided by Harold.

So why are they so desperate to save the Machine in the end of Season 4? In fact, team Machine is worried about the Machine in Season 3 and 4, as Samaritan came online and started searching for the Machine.

But why can't Harold make a new machine?

Answer (score 6):

### Because the Machine learns

Yes, Harold provided the initial data and structure but Machine had to incorporate what Harold had taught it over several iterations and years.

From there, the Machine learned for itself from observing not only Harold but other people and *self-programmed*.

A simple analogy is a human (which is the point)....if a person dies, you can make another one **but it wouldn't have the same experiences and knowledge as the original**.

Could Harold have built a new *physical* Machine...yes, but it would have taken too much time to teach it everything all over again.

Comment: I also thought that Harold was never really sure what was different about Machine number 43 so that it was the loving machine we know rather than a murderous one like its previous iterations.